# Как вычислить на этапе компиляции каким типом объявлен enum class?

Tags: c++, c++17, метапрограммирование

Как вычислить на этапе компиляции каким типом объявлен enum class?

Тоесть, у меня есть enum class

```
enum class Test : uint8_t
{
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}
```

Как мне на этапе компиляции исходя из типа Test получить тип uint8_t?

Comment: [`std::underlying_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type): `std::underlying_type<Test>::type` или `std::underlying_type_t<Test>`.